# How to solve xor equations with multiple variable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I have 9 variables $$a_1,a_2,a_3 ... a_9 $$ and want to extract their values using the following equations.
$$
a_1 \oplus a_4 = D1
$$
$$
a_2 \oplus a_5 = D2
$$
$$
a_3 \oplus a_6 = D3
$$
$$
a_4 \oplus a_7 = D4
$$
$$
a_5 \oplus a_8 = D5
$$
$$
a_6 \oplus a_9 = D6
$$
$$
a_1 \oplus a_7 = D7
$$
$$
a_2 \oplus a_8 = D8
$$
$$
a_3 \oplus a_9 = D9
$$
$$D1, D2, D3, ... D9 $$ are given interger values. 
How to solve this kind of question or specifically this question?

Comment: Hi Vikas and welcome to MSE. You're more likely to receive help if you demonstrate some effort on your own part.

Comment: $$a_1 \oplus a_4 = D1$$ is equivalent to $$a_1 + a_4 = D1 \pmod 2$$.  So you can solve this like any system of linear equations, just do all the arithmetic mod 2.

Answer (score 1):

The system need not be consistent.

To be consistent, we require $$D_1 \oplus D_4 = D_7$$

$$D_2 \oplus D_5 = D_8$$

$$D_3 \oplus D_6 = D_9$$

Suppose those conditions are satisfied, the whole system of equations is equivalent to the first $6$ equations.

We have $6$ independent equations and $9$ variables, we have $3$ degree of freedom. Fix $a_7, a_8, a_9$, use backward substitution to solve for the other variables.

Remark: Notice that this is a linear system of equations, we can use Gaussian elimination.

Comment: How to fix a7,a8,a9? can you please explain?

Comment: there are some degree of freedom (meaning the solution is not unique) let them be whatever that you want and you can express the rest in terms of them, for example $a_6 = D_6 \oplus a_9$.

Comment: and how to apply backward substitution while having xor in equations?

Comment: for example, after I express $a_6 = D_6 \oplus a_9$, I also know that $a_3 = D_3 \oplus a_6 = D_3 \oplus D_6 \oplus a_9$.

Comment: ok i understand the equation $$ a_6 = D6 \oplus a_9$$.

Comment: But when i solve it i find a7,a8,a9 are attached with values of a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6 since those are variables how i get rid of them?

Comment: those are free variables, your system doesn't have unique solution. you decide the free variables and then they determine the rest.

Comment: ok thanks. i will try.